# How to see usage of each core in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, cpu, task-manager

The *Performance* tab of the Task Manager shows this:

[image: Task Manager]

i.e. the CPU usage, and the number of cores (and logical cores) I have available.

Can I get a graph like this for each core to see whether something is indeed running parallel or not (e.g. some `multiprocessing` stuff on Python)?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Right click on graph -> Change graph to -> Logical processors

It will show you the usage of each **logical** processor.

[image: Screenshot of the answer]

Comment: Somewhat related: Starting with Windows 8, if your CPU has many cores, the view will show heatmaps instead of graphs: https://www.tested.com/tech/windows/3097-windows-8-simplifies-cpu-load-monitoring-with-heat-maps/

Comment: To all the people looking at this view: just stop. This view is extremely misleading. Unless your threads have CPU affinity specified, Windows **WILL** spread the load across all the cores as equally as it can. This view is pointless.

Comment: If you try to multithread an application that consumes little CPU time, then yes: it is not possible to analyze is the multiple CPU usage from here. But if the application consumes a lot, actually itis possible to have an idea of what is going on.

Comment: @RomanSt: That is misleading/incomplete. A single thread runs on a single core at any given moment. Windows may move it to other cores occasionally. Yet, a single thread is not spread at any given moment, only the collection of _all the threads_ is "spread", or if you look at a temporal aggregate.  With that knowledge in petto, I don't see why the view is misleading. It shows core usage, not more, not less.

Answer (score -1):

What you want is the Resource Monitor.
From the Task Manager you can start the Resource Monitor by clicking on the 3 dots in the upper-right corner.